# Formula for eigendecomposition of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, positive-definite

In some books/[notes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543/square-root-of-symmetric-matrix-and-transposition), the eigendecomposition of positive definite matrix $\bf A$ is written as

\begin{align*}
{\bf A} = {\bf P}^{\bf T}{\bf \Lambda}{\bf P} \Longrightarrow {\bf \Lambda} = {\bf P}{\bf A}{\bf P}^{\bf T} 
\end{align*}
where $\bf \Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are the eigenvalues of ${\bf A}$, while in some other books/notes, the reversed:

\begin{align*}
{\bf A} = {\bf P}{\bf \Lambda}{\bf P}^{\bf T} \Longrightarrow {\bf \Lambda} = {\bf P}^{\bf T}{\bf A}{\bf P} 
\end{align*}
is used. I tried both formulas using a symmetric matrix, for example,

\begin{align*}
{\bf A} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
with eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2}=-1,4$ (which means it is not positive definite) and eigenvectors $(1,-2)^{\bf T}$ and $(1,1/2)^{\bf T}$, respectively, and found out the formulas are not equivalent since (using normalised eigenvectors)

\begin{align*}
{\bf P}{\bf A}{\bf P}^{\bf T} &= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\ -2 & 1 
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 
\end{array}\right]
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -2 \\ 2 & 1 
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
11/5 & -12/5 \\ -12/5 & 4/5 
\end{array}\right]  \\
{\bf P}^{\bf T}{\bf A}{\bf P} &= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -2 \\ 2 & 1 
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 
\end{array}\right]
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\ -2 & 1 
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}

When I took a positive definite matrix, 
\begin{align*}
{\bf A} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
with eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2}=2,4$ and eigenvectors $(1,-1)^{\bf T}$ and $(1,1)^{\bf T}$, respectively, the formulas are also not equivalent since (again using normalised eigenvectors)

\begin{align*}
{\bf P}{\bf A}{\bf P}^{\bf T} &= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 
\end{array}\right]
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
4 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 
\end{array}\right]  \\
{\bf P}^{\bf T}{\bf A}{\bf P} &= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 
\end{array}\right]
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}

When I took another positive definite matrix, 
\begin{align*}
{\bf A} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
with eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2,3}=1,2,3$ and eigenvectors $(1,1,0)^{\bf T}$, $(0,0,1)^{\bf T}$ and $(1,-1,0)^{\bf T}$, respectively, the output is difference since

\begin{align*}
{\bf P}{\bf A}{\bf P}^{\bf T} &= 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1/\sqrt{2} & 0 & 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 
1\sqrt{2} & 0 & -1/\sqrt{2} \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\  
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1/\sqrt{2}  & 1/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\  
1\sqrt{2}  & -1/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 
\end{array}\right] 
= 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 0 & -1/\sqrt{2} \\ 
0 & 2 & -1/\sqrt{2} \\ 
-1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2} & 2 \\  
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
{\bf P}^{\bf T}{\bf A}{\bf P} &= 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1/\sqrt{2}  & 1/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\  
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1/\sqrt{2} & 0 & 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 
1/\sqrt{2} & 0 & -1/\sqrt{2} \\  
0  & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}\right] 
= 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 3 \\  
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}

So, it seems that I can conclude that ${\bf A} = {\bf P}{\bf \Lambda}{\bf P}^{\bf T} \Longrightarrow {\bf \Lambda} = {\bf P}^{\bf T}{\bf A}{\bf P} $ is correct and it is not equivalent with ${\bf A} = {\bf P}^{\bf T}{\bf \Lambda}{\bf P} \Longrightarrow {\bf \Lambda} = {\bf P}{\bf A}{\bf P}^{\bf T}$. Am I missing something that has caused me to get different answers for both formulas?

Comment: The formulas are not equivalent effectively. The other formula is correct, if by convention we assume that the eigenvectors are the rows of $P$ and not the columns. Personnaly, I was only knowing and using $A = P \Lambda P^T$ formula, assuming here that the eigenvectors are the colums of $P$

Comment: And likewise, I have only ever known the second formulation! IMO I think that the second  formulation should be used as it is then compatible with the usual presentation of the Schur decomposition $A = UTU^*$. For normal (including symmetric) matrices, this reduces to the eigendecomposition of $A$ in the second formulation

Comment: I hope you realize that the matrix $P$ in $PAP^T$ is not the same matrix as the $P$ in $P^TAP$. As other comments have noted, in one the eigenvectors are rows, on the other they’re columns. Use a different name for one of them if that’s confusing you.

Comment: thanks very much. It's silly that I didn't realise that the eigenvectors can be written in rows and columns. thanks very much!